# Python continuous input

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a problem with a while loop. Basically the program should continuously ask the user to input the item price until they enter 'Done', and print the total bill. For context I'll put my code at the moment.

```
a = float(input('Price? '))
count = 0
while a > 0:
  b = float(input('Price? '))
  count += b
if a == 'Done':
   print('Total is $', count)
```

Comment: The condition of the `while` loop, `a`, never changes, so the loop either never executes or never stops… The `if a == 'Done'` check needs to happen somewhere inside the loop if you want to use it as condition to end the loop…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count = 0
while True:
    a = input('Price? ')
    if a == 'Done':
        print('Total is $', count)
        break
    count += float(a)
```

Note that this code breaks if the user inputs a string that is not either "Done" or a float literal. For that you would need to surround the `count += float(a)` line with a try / except block.